# Oracle - how to use oracle variable to create a oracle user?

Tags: oracle

I want to create a oracle user with a oracle variable in a script file, not PL/SQL client.

something like this:

```
define var DBUSERNAME = 'AAA';

CREATE USER '&DBUSERNAME' PROFILE "DEFAULT" IDENTIFIED BY "pwd123" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP" ACCOUNT UNLOCK
BEGIN
DBMS_WM.GrantSystemPriv('ACCESS_ANY_WORKSPACE', '&DBUSERNAME', 'NO');
END;

GRANT ADMINISTER ANY SQL TUNING SET TO '&DBUSERNAME'
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER TO '&DBUSERNAME'
BEGIN
dbms_resource_manager_privs.grant_system_privilege(privilege_name=>'ADMINISTER_RESOURCE_MANAGER', grantee_name=>'&DBUSERNAME', admin_option=>FALSE);
END;

GRANT ADMINISTER SQL TUNING SET TO '&DBUSERNAME'
GRANT ADVISOR TO '&DBUSERNAME'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For the DDL calls the user name should not be in quotes:

```
define var DBUSERNAME = 'AAA';

CREATE USER &DBUSERNAME PROFILE "DEFAULT" ...
```

It would be acceptable for it to be in *double* quotes, but I'd suggest you only do that if you're sure the name would be set as uppercase to avoid future case issues - better to skip the quotes to avoid that. (You don't really need the double quotes around the profile, password etc. in the `create` call either as long as you don't have anything with odd names, but utilities like `get_ddl` always include them to be safe). Although if they aren't in upper case anyway then the procedure calls might not recognise the name.

The only places in your script you need single quotes is in the calls to `GrantSystemPriv` and `grant_system_privilege`, where you are passing a string as a parameter.

You are also missing a semi-colon after your DDL statements, and a terminating `/` after your anonymous PL/SQL blocks:

```
GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER TO &DBUSERNAME;
```

and

```
BEGIN
    dbms_resource_manager_privs.grant_system_privilege(
        privilege_name=>'ADMINISTER_RESOURCE_MANAGER',
        grantee_name=>'&DBUSERNAME',
        admin_option=>FALSE);
END;
/
```

etc.